# R: Nested list changes when assigning empty vectors

Tags: r, list, nested

Say I create a empty nested list first:

```
prt=list()
for (i in 1:240) {
    prt[[i]]=list()
    for (j in 1:12) {
        prt[[i]][[j]]=list()
    }
}
```

Then I want to assign empty vectors to each list

```
for (i in 1:240) {
    for (j in 1:12) {
        prt[[i]][[j]]=c()
    }
}
```

What I get is 240 list each with 6 lists

```
prt[[1]]
[[1]]
list()

[[2]]
list()

[[3]]
list()

[[4]]
list()

[[5]]
list()

[[6]]
list()
```

What's wrong with this and how can I make it 12?

Comment: Why are we creating empty list, why not create while doing the calculations, using nested lapply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c()` is `NULL`, not an empty vector. Assigning it to an element just deletes that element rather converting it to an empty vector.

This means in the second loop, when `j` is 1, you are deleting the first element of each list by making it `NULL`. Since you have deleted the first element, the element that *was* second is now first, so it doesn't get deleted, but the old third element does, and so on. Therefore all the odd numbered list elements are deleted and the even-numbered ones are preserved. This leaves 6 elements in each member of `prt`.

We can confirm this if we put numbers into the original lists:

```r
prt <- list()

for (i in 1:240) {
    prt[[i]] <- list()
    for (j in 1:12) {
        prt[[i]][[j]] = list(j)
    }
}

for (i in 1:240) {
    for (j in 1:12) {
        prt[[i]][[j]] <- c()
    }
}

prt[[1]]
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]][[1]]
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [[4]][[1]]
#> [1] 8
#> 
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [[5]][[1]]
#> [1] 10
#> 
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [[6]][[1]]
#> [1] 12
```

If you want to insert an empty vector, use `numeric(0)` instead of `c()`, so your second loop would be:

```r
for (i in 1:240) {
    for (j in 1:12) {
        prt[[i]][[j]] <- numeric(0)
    }
}
```

Better still, use `lapply` and avoid any explicit loops at all. The following single line creates the same structure your entire example is aiming to create:

```r
lapply(1:240, function(x) lapply(1:12, function(y) numeric(0)))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Good answer! Although `prt[[i]][[j]][[1]] = c()` also worked for me.

Comment: You can also `rep` function @AlexLee, should be much faster. `rep(list(rep(list(numeric(0)),12)),  240)`